# Batch file: %%d was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

Trying to execute the following command inside a batch file

```
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%d in ("%date%") do rename "cam1.avi" %%e-%%f-%%g.avi
```

and I now get the response

%%d was unexpected at this time.

The strange thing is that this command worked fine until a couple of weeks ago and it still works on another computer, all running windows 8.1

Comment: works ok for me. In a batchfile. On the commandline, this gives the described error. (on commandline, use `%d` instead of `%%d` - this works for me)

Comment: There appears to be nothing wrong with that line in particular. Perhaps you need to show a few lines either side of that single statement. I suspect it's within a block.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a space between `delims=/` and the `"`

Comment: yes, there is, but this is not a problem. A space is a valid delimiter.